# Author Fields into a content type template

Tags: entities, users, 8, theming

I'm trying to load some of the information from the author into a **node--article.html.twig**. So I can provide some information like bio, social media,etc.

Similar to this...

[image]

I can easily get the `author_name` and the `author_picture` because these two are given by the template. I added extra field at `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` in this case the only extra field is `field_bio`

[image]

I try to use the **include** to add this user field into.

**node--article.html.twig**

```
<h4>{{ author_name }}</h4>
<p>{% include('field--user--field-bio--user.html.twig') %}</p>
```

This what I have on the field template - **field--user--field-bio--user.html.twig**

```
<span{{ attributes }}>
  {%- for item in items -%}
      {{ item.content }}
  {%- endfor -%}
</span>

<p>Hello</p>
```

The word "Hello" is been display on the **node--article.html.twig**; however, the `item.content` which is my field information is not been load. =(

I also try to dig up into the user variables by using `{{ kint() }}` to see if there is this information and I did not find it either.

I have seen some example with a module, which I have avoid them because this is for a contrib theme and I do not want to have any module dependency. I have done this many times with DS but I do not want to use any extra module.

So I have couple questions...

- Should I use **include** for this use case or not ?

  - If I have too, what I'm doing wrong ? Why the `item.content` is not been load ?
  - If I should not use it in this use case, what should I do instead ?

Comment: You should pass the required arguments in a preprocess function

Comment: Why not make a block view and place an instance for pages that are of Article node type?

Comment: Check out in the Manage Display. Maybe this field is excluded. Otherwise, it should be there in the template as a variable. Have you tried dumping all the vars like here? https://www.drupal.org/node/1906780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use include for this use case or not ?

This is not possible, you can't mix different templates like node and field because they have different variables.

> If I have too, what I'm doing wrong ? Why the item.content is not been
>   load ?

item.content is only loaded in field, not in node template.

> If I should not use it in this use case, what should I do instead ?

You should define the user field you need in preprocess, examples for the two fields already defined:

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['author_name'] = drupal_render($variables['elements']['uid']);
  $variables['author_picture'] = user_view($node->getOwner(), 'compact');
```

A basic example to use this in your own hook:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['user_field1'] = $node->getOwner()->field_field1->value;
```

And in twig

```
{{ user_field1 }}
```

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of deprecated `drupal_render()`.

Comment: @kenorb, this is a code example from core, so you should file an issue to change this

Comment: @kenorb, renderRoot() is not a replacement for drupal_render().  This would be render().

Comment: Ok, good to know, as `drupal_render` or `render` just doesn't work sometimes properly, `render()` as well sometimes fails to render arrays, so my understanding that `renderRoot()` method is for final render to render everything just in case.

Comment: @kenorb, in cases where render() doesn't work properly the best solution is most times not to render at all. In D8 site building is done 99 % with unrendered render arrays. And yes, renderRoot() is for final render, but final means, you deliver it right away, like in a response.